# Where are the Start Menu window dimensions/size stored?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

In Windows 10 you can resize the Start Menu by click/dragging its borders.  I'm assuming this information is stored or encoded somewhere for each user since the Start Menu remembers the dimensions after rebooting etc, and each user can have their own independent Start Menu size.

Where/how are the dimensions for the Windows 10 Start Menu stored?